# Issue of Regular Expression for URL pattern on POSTGRES

Tags: regex, postgresql, url-pattern, greenplum

```
select regexp_replace('https://www.facebook.com/cricket/hello', '.*\..*?\/', '')
```

The above code is giving me

> hello

instead of

> cricket/hello

I checked on Regexp checking website and the pattern is correct.
I am not sure where am I going wrong.

> DBMS: "PostgreSQL 8.2.15 (Greenplum Database 4.2.8.3 build 1) on
>   x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 4.4.2 compiled on
>   Nov 2 2014 01:33:14"

Comment: What are you trying to do rather than get cricket/hello ?
Is this a school or training assignment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how, but this worked

```
.*?\.[a-z]+\/
```

Taking Andrew Wolfe's query on weirdest kinds of URLs.

```
select testval, regexp_replace ( testval,  '.*?\.[a-z]+\/',  '')
from (
    select 'https://www.facebook.com/cricket/hello' as testval
  union all
  select 'http://a.b.co.uk/cric.ke.t/hello' as testval
  union all
  select 'ftp://a.b.com.d.e.f/relroot/cricket/hello' as testval  union all
  select 'http://www.google.co.uk/cricket/hello' as testval  
  union all
  select 'http://a.b.co.uk/cricket/hello/this/is/a/little/longer?and&it=has&args' as testval
) vals
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select regexp_replace('https://www.facebook.com/cricket/hello', '.*\.[a-z]+\/', '')
```

Also work with cctld's :

```
select regexp_replace('https://www.google.co.uk/cricket/hello', '.*\.[a-z]+\/', '')
```

Comment: @Ashish - Pedro's answer works fine for your example - are you just trying to make this work for that one example?  Otherwise, I would recommend you think carefully about the requirements and update your question (or accept this answer and post a new question).  btw, it looks like the issue with your code is that `regexp_replace` is matching greedy (up the the last `/`).

Comment: I have other URLs as well like **www.google.co.uk/cricket/hello** and the answer would not work on this example.
@steveklein , you are right about the greediness issue. Although I have used the non-greedy version, the `regexp_replace`  is still going greedy. How can I solve this.

Comment: I've updated my answer, give it a try. It works with any gtld or cctld.

Comment: @PedroLobito Did not work. It still gave **hello** as the result. I believe there is some issue with GreenPlum.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you want the path part of a URL.

I don't have my pg up but I'd go very explicit with each part of the URL -

```
'[^:]+:\/\/[A-Za-z][-a-zA-Z0-9]*(\.[A-Za-z][-a-zA-Z0-9]*)*/'
```

A test:

```
select testval, regexp_replace ( testval,  '[^:]+:\/\/[A-Za-z][-a-zA-Z0-9]*(\.[A-Za-z][-a-zA-Z0-9]*)*/',  '')
from (
    select 'https://www.facebook.com/cricket/hello' as testval
  union all
  select 'http://a.b.co.uk/cric.ke.t/hello' as testval
  union all
  select 'ftp://a.b.com.d.e.f/relroot/cricket/hello' as testval  union all
  select 'http://www.google.co.uk/cricket/hello' as testval  
  union all
  select 'http://a.b.co.uk/cricket/hello/this/is/a/little/longer?and&it=has&args' as testval
) vals
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb/857/0

Comment: This looks great but still did not work on GreenPlum. The first four gave **hello** as results and the last one gave **longer?and&it=has&args**